# Is there a way to keep AWS Kafka triggers enabled when there is a Kafka outage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-msk

Our Amazon MSK Kafka ran out of space and during this outage all lambda triggers were disabled automatically. After fixing the Kafka issue we had to manually enable all triggers to get the system running.

Is there a way to keep lambda triggers enabled after a Kafka outage?